# swift 3 how to use CFArrayCreate

Tags: swift3, unsafe-pointers, unsafemutablepointer

I'd like to create a CFArray from an Array

previously in Swift 2, I'm able to do this:

```
let array = [0, 1, 2, 3]
let arrayPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Void>>(array)
let cfArray = CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, arrayPointer, array.count, nil)
```

now in Swift 3 CFArrayCreate is expecting `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?>!` as the second parameter

one way I attempted to do it is as such:

```
let array: [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3]
var rawPointer: UnsafeRawPointer? = UnsafeRawPointer(array)
let cfArray = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &rawPointer) { ppArray in
    CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, ppArray, array.count, nil)
}
```

however this will create CFArray with element of [value of rawPointer, garbage, garbage, garbage] instead of [0, 1, 2, 3]

how would I go about making this `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?>!` parameter out of the array ?

Comment: Are you sure your Swift 2 code is exactly the same as you have used. A slight difference would result in a big difference when working with pointers. Please re-check it, the code crashes in my Playground of Xcode 7.3.1.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
let cfArray = array as CFArray
```